# Apache Allow Ip range with SetEnvIfExpr

Tags: apache

I have this task to manage:
in my apache server (act as a proxy server) i need to allow access only to some subnetwork. Because it's behind a WAF (Incapsula) i try to extract the IP to admit from the **X-Forwarded-For**  and match with this

```
SetEnvIfExpr "req('X-Forwarded-For') =~ /(^.*,\s*|^)(.*)$/ && $2 -ipmatch '54.93.255.128/27'" AllowIP
```

Instead works something like this

```
SetEnvIF X-Forwarded-For "54.93.255.139" AllowIP
```

but in this case the number of the IPs are too large to manage

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

I solve with this:
I added these directive to fetch the second ($2) IP collected by the X-Forwarded-For and then I matched with ipmatch to the subnet mask I need to check:

```
    SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-For "^(.*,\s*)(.*)(,\s*.*)$" ip_to_catch=$2
  SetEnvIFExpr "env('ip_to_catch') -ipmatch '66.91.255.128/27'" AllowIP
```

And at the endI added this to check the AllowIP value before grant access to my resources:

```
<RequireAll>
      Require env AllowIP
  </RequireAll>
```